# C# - convert any filetype to bitmap show in picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, converters, bitstream

I want a OpenFileDialog to select any file-types and show the file bits in a bitmap image. I mean the selected file contain some 0/1 bits, I want to show them in black and white image. Any Idea?

Comment: Write a function that converts arbitrary bytes to a Bitmap image and then load that.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a valid image file, you can simply read an image like this:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(pathOfImage);
```

...and then assign it to a picture box.

You will need a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and include a `using using System.Drawing;` at the top of your code.

---

If the bits in the file, however, represent the black and white pixels, you will need to draw the image yourself.

First create a `Bitmap`, then create a graphics object from it. You can then draw the pixels on it.

```
using (var image = new Bitmap(width, height))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
    // TODO: Draw using the graphics object. (Insert code below)
}
```

You can use the answer from this answer to read the bits: [BinaryReader - Reading a Single “ BIT ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455806/880990)

In a double loop you can then iterate through the bits. Assuming that the bits are stored line by line:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("file.dat", FileMode.Open)) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            bool? bit = stream.ReadBit(true);
            if (bit == null) { // No more bits
                return; 
            }
            if (bit.Value) {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally assign the image to the picture box

```
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

Comment: The files are not valid images. He wants a black and white representation of the bit fields of any arbitrary file.

Comment: Ok, that's confusing, as valid image files also consist of 0 and 1 bits.

Comment: Instead of a Graphics object I would use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits(v=vs.110).aspx) with a 1 bit per pixel Bitmap.  (Would write a answer but I am limited to my phone today)

Comment: Yes LockBits is very fast, but also very low-level. It is described in this answer: [Fast work with Bitmaps in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1563170/880990).

Comment: You can also use the `DirectBitmap` class from SaxxonPike: [C# - Faster Alternatives to SetPixel and GetPixel for Bitmaps for Windows Forms App](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34801225/880990). You can set pixels with `directBitmap.Bits[y * Width + x] = color.ToArgb();`

Comment: I tried this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2426395/6268039
Now I have a file full of 0 and 1, So the problem remaining is to show these 0 and 1 in a custom height and width of black and white pixel

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2426395/6268039 have limitation on file size!!

Comment: This gets you the bytes, not the bits! In order to get the bits, use the link in my answer.

Comment: No, my output file include only 0 and 1. how could it be byte? Its all 0 and 1, Isn't it bits?

Comment: This `byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename);` reads a byte-array! Of course the files contains bits, but you don't get them 1 by 1, but packed into bytes, 8 at a time. Each byte contains 8 bits. [BinaryReader - Reading a Single “ BIT ”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455790/binaryreader-reading-a-single-bit/9455806#9455806) tells you how to get single bits. It unpacks the bytes into bits.